# how to map a custom type to database in ef code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

For the first time I'm doing EF Code-first and my entity has a property of type `IDateRange` It's definition is like this :

```
public class PartyClassification 
{
   public IDateRange EffectiveDate { get; set; }
   /* 
     other properties ...
   */
}

public interface IDateRange : IRange<DateTime>
{
}

public interface IRange<T>
{
    T From { get; set; }
    T To { get; set; }
}
```

All other my properties which is simple clr type converted to appropriate type in db , but not EffectiveDate . I expect EffectiveDate converted in two DateTime Column in db.

I'm wondering if I could do that by [custom convention](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions) or there is a better way ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I suggest reading [this 3-part article series](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx).
I don't think it talks about handling Interfaces, but it tells you ways in which Abstract classes and class hierarchy in the model can be mapped to your database.

Comment: I pasted the link but it is not showing as a link. If the above link doesn't work, you can copy that into your browser or search for 'Inheritance with EF Code First' and you will find it.

Comment: I fixed the link, but I fail to see how it applies to the question.

Comment: If his design allows using Abstract classes, this article provides details how to do it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: No mention of abstract classes. Maybe complex types are closer to what the OP wants.